# How show Additional information product to product post page?

Tags: product

I use theme flatsome. now i want show fields in tab Additional information outside the page product. i have screenshot under. Please help me, thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGmeu.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieNFQ.png

Comment: update please help me

Comment: Update please help me